# Graph implementation knowing edges ahead of time

Tags: data-structures, graph, hashtable, adjacency-list

I'm looking for an efficent way to implement a weighted undirected graph knowing only the number of edges ahead of time.

sample input: 
N (number of edges) 
 
A B x (x is the distance from A to B) 
. 
.

I've thinked to use adjacency lists of Node* (I need to know neighbours) and stored nodes in a dynamic hash table (I don't know how many nodes I'll take so I need a dynamic - search/insert - container).

Are there better ways to do it?

Sorry for my bad english! :D

Answer (score 0):

Given the format you're getting the input in, a very reasonable approach would be to use either a hash table of lists, where the keys are the nodes and the values are lists of pairs of (node, distance).  Alternatively, if you have a dense graph and want to be able to quickly determine the distance from one node to another, it might be good to have a hash table of hash tables, where the top level hash table maps nodes to a second hash table, which then maps each node the original node has an edge to to its cost.  This still lets you iterate across a node's outgoing edges, but gives you faster lookup of distances.

Another idea (depending on the use case) would be to start off by building the first data structure (the hash table of lists), then to post process it by building an adjacency matrix.  This would be useful if you didn't need to iterate across a node's outgoing edges and needed fast random access to distances between nodes.  It is similar to the hash table of hash tables, but is probably more space efficient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

As you said I did a hash table of lists (node, distance). I don't know the graph density, I need a data structure that can adapt to find a minimum spanning tree getting the input in that format (thinking about Prim's algorithm)...

Comment: @user1987545- If you need to find an MST, you can just use a hash table mapping from nodes to lists.  That said, if you know the nodes are always numbers from 1 to n for some unknown n, a standard dynamic array of lists might be more appropriate.